# why can't i see the signed_request in all my facebook application pages?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my facebook app consists of some php pages
it the first page appears in the canvas url i can get the user data from the signed_request parameter like this:

```
 $app_id = "1111111111111111";

 $canvas_page = "http://www.mydomain.com/fb/app/";

 $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,read_stream";


 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];


 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
        echo 'welcome user';
      }
```

but when i navigate to other pages or a page in an iframe within my app i can't see this parameter.
so is it only the first page loaded in the canvas that the facebook sends this parame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  Only the first page loaded into the iframe will receive the signed_request parameter.  It is up to you to parse it there and then carry whatever data you need to subsequent pages.

Comment: ok, i tried to set a cookie with value of the signed_request but i can't get its value from any page even from the first page.

Comment: What browser are you using? You are likely running into the dreaded third-party cookie problem. Check your settings to enable third-party cookies, and see if it works for you then.

Comment: well i'm using IE and google chrome , i couldn't set the cookie in the usual way by setcookie(cookiename,cookievalue); and the application is not navigating to other pages in chrome. but i started to send the signed request parameter to every page i open, and it works. thanks "Floyd Wilburn" :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)  You might want to take a look at http://www.braintilt.com/fbcookies.php for some more explanation and a way to more easily move the data from page to page.